# `Overfull \hbox` with pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, width

I'm getting an "Overfull \hbox" error when setting `width=\textwidth` in axis when using `pgfplots`.

Here is a MWE. The exact error shown is `Overfull \hbox (6.19328pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--23`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
      \centering   % interestingly. removing this increase the error to `23.19328pt too wide`
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={Y label},
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            width={\textwidth},
        ]

          \addplot[]
          coordinates {
            (0,21.70)(1,21.71)(8,20.93)(9,20.47)(10,20.40) % Something. Doesn't really matter
          };
          \addlegendentry{Precision}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I read a lot of answers here and around the web, but nothing seems to work. And being relatively new, I'm not able to debug further.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's the ylabel sticking out because the plot is already text width wide. It's a just a warning

Comment: Thanks @percusse. What do you mean by just a warning? Is is not actually sticking out in the margin. If it is, any idea about how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: without `\centering` the picture is starting a justified paragraph so is indented by `\parindent` which is why the box is overfull by an increased amount.

Comment: `width=\textwidth` uses `\textwidth`- 45pt for the plot and 45pt for the material outside of the plotting area. The 45pt are a fixed length. But 45pt are not enough horizontal space for the `ylabel` and the xtick `10` in the lower right  corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

to the preamble to see what's going on.

- The left image is the code as given. You see that the label `10` exceeds the text width.
- The right image is with the `\centering` removed. The image protrudes even more since now the image starts a new paragraph that begins with an indentation. If you replace `\centering` by `\noindent` the image will be typeset without indentation flushleft.

  [image]     
  [image]

A solution is to replace

```
width={\textwidth}
```

by

```
width={\dimexpr\textwidth-7pt}
```

where `7pt` corresponds to the amount reported by TeX in the overfull hbox message.

[image]

Just to make sure: The line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` is only for test purposes, remove it in the final version.

Finally, here is the code for the picture (without frame).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
      \noindent
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={Y label},
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            width={\dimexpr\textwidth-7pt},
        ]
          \addplot[]
          coordinates {(0,21.70)(1,21.71)(8,20.93)(9,20.47)(10,20.40)};
          \addlegendentry{Precision}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Automatic adjustment:** The adjustment can be automated by using the `adjustbox` package. The following code will resize "Some LaTeX material" to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
   ... some LaTeX material ...
\end{adjustbox}
...
\end{document}
```

Here is the code for the example above.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={Y label},
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            width={\textwidth},
        ]
          \addplot[]
          coordinates {
            (0,21.70)(1,21.71)(8,20.93)(9,20.47)(10,20.40)
          };
          \addlegendentry{Precision}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried similar solution and it works! :)
But I have multiple such diagrams with different overfull-ness. Is there any better way than to fix each of them by the amount they're overfull?

Comment: @nisargjhaveri I have added another solution that resizes the plot automatically.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the solution with `adjustbox` scales the whole diagram, changing the font size and everything, while the earlier solution of setting the width, does not change the font size or line widths.
Is there any way we can know the diagram's to-be width and set the width parameter accordingly. As @esdd suggested, it leaves 45pt for everything else, is there a way to fix it there?
Btw, this works. Thanks a lot. :D And, sorry for being so demanding! :P

Comment: @nisargjhaveri The rescaling will be minimal if you use `\textwidth` also in the plot. Another solution is to choose an upper bound, say `15pt`, and always subtract this amount from `\textwidth`. I can think of solutions where you typeset the plot, then measure the width, and then typeset it a second time with an adjusted `width`. But this seems to be an overkill.